# From the Views 3 and weight modules, which features sub-group reordering?

Tags: views

This question is for users of any solution listed as a [Node Ordering Module](http://drupal.org/node/398508) and used the module in a Views view page (especially Views 3 and Drupal 7) to order list under a sub-category.

The goal is a Views view with a list grouped by taxo/category. The individual items of each category may be reordered on a Views' admin page but *only* within each category. (for example, if you had a list of albums on a fan site, it would not be correct to move a song from one album to another.)

I already know, Draggable Views does not work in this manner as per the ["group by"](http://drupal.org/node/566332) issue for this module.

Without trying each module, anyone use this "pattern"? Or, is one of these modules a *better starting point* to hack from (and why)?